# The merge feature does not kick in - Stack Overflow thinks that the users are two separate users

Tags: support, openid, merge-accounts, facebook, google-openid

I have apparently recently created a user using Facebook login, and this will not merge into my main account (which uses OpenID and Google).

When using the "merge procedure", a screen just shows up telling me:

> *"Facebook (endre@stolsvik.com) belongs to another user (Endre Stølsvik) You can log in as Endre Stølsvik or cancel to stay logged in as stolsvik"*.

How can I fix this?